# Is there a way to change OUT_DIR for a build.rs

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, clap, structopt

Currently I'm trying to write a `build.rs` that creates a bunch of autocompletion scripts for a cli app.

```rust
// build.rs
fn main() {
    let outdir = match std::env::var_os("OUT_DIR") {
        None => return,
        Some(outdir) => outdir,
    };

    Args::clap().gen_completions("monk", structopt::clap::Shell::Bash, outdir.clone());
    ...
}
```

Currently this outputs the autocomplete scripts in `./target/debug/build/monk-cli-43148fdfeeafb947/out/monk.bash`. I would like to package these scripts in a CICD pipeline, but the path to the scripts is inconsistent. Is there a way that I could have these files output to a consistent directory like `./target/completions/monk.bash`, or should I be doing this autocomplete script generation somewhere other than build.rs?

Comment: there is a flag in cargo --out-dir to do this, but is still in nightly version see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html

Comment: I can't use nightly on the code that I'm working on.